# Making "Snipping Tool" from Python using Wx and PyAutoGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets, pyautogui

I am trying to make a snipping tool using the Wx and PyAutoGui modules, I am stuck at a certain problem: The saved image file is at wrong position (see image below)

[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq1pQ.png)

As you can see I am trying to grab a specific region, that is the red rectangle, and save those pixels in that region to the file "my_screenshot.png". However, the position/coordinates seems to be off (you can see the rectangles, which was supposed to be the region of the screenshot)

Here are the codes:

```
import wx
import pyautogui

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):

    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=wx.DisplaySize())

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=self.GetSize())

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

        self.SetTransparent(50)

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))
        region = (self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        pyautogui.screenshot('my_screenshot.png', region=region)
        print("MouseUp: " + str(region))
        self.Hide()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None: return

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0), wx.TRANSPARENT))

        region = (self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        print("Draw: " + str(region))


    def PrintPosition(self, pos):
        return str(pos.x) + " " + str(pos.y)


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = SelectableFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

        return True


app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

From what I've gathered that, it took the width and height, but wrong x and y position, how can I fix that? Thank you

EDIT: There seems to be values difference between these functions

```
    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()
        print("MouseDown[event]: " + str(self.c1))
        print("MouseDown[gui]: "+  str(pyautogui.position()))
```

Output:

```
MouseDown[event]: (729, 484)
MouseDown[gui]: Point(x=737, y=515)
```

The offset is +8 for x, and +31 for y. How did this incontinence happen? My hotfix would be to add those offsets to the pyautogui.screenshot command but I don't think that is the right fix and would not be guaranteed to be the same offset values for other screen sizes..

GMM

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# load the iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# select first two columns
X = iris.data[:, :2]

# turn it into a dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame(X)

# plot the data
plt.scatter(d[0], d[1])
plt.show()

# RUN
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 3)

# Fit the GMM model for the dataset
# which expresses the dataset as a
# mixture of 3 Gaussian Distribution
gmm.fit(d)

# assign a label to each sample
labels = gmm.predict(d)
d['labels'] = labels
d0 = d[d['labels'] == 0]
d1 = d[d['labels'] == 1]
d2 = d[d['labels'] == 2]

# plot three clusters in same plot
plt.scatter(d0[0], d0[1], c='r')
plt.scatter(d1[0], d1[1], c='yellow')
plt.scatter(d2[0], d2[1], c='g')
plt.show()

# print the converged log-likelihood value
print(gmm.lower_bound_)

# print the number of interations needed
# for the log-likelihood value to converge
print(gmm.n_iter_)
```

DBScan

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# load the iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# select first two columns
X = iris.data[:, :2]

# turn it into a dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame(X)

# plot the data
plt.scatter(d[0], d[1])
plt.show()

# RUN
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 3)

# Fit the GMM model for the dataset
# which expresses the dataset as a
# mixture of 3 Gaussian Distribution
gmm.fit(d)

# assign a label to each sample
labels = gmm.predict(d)
d['labels'] = labels
d0 = d[d['labels'] == 0]
d1 = d[d['labels'] == 1]
d2 = d[d['labels'] == 2]

# plot three clusters in same plot
plt.scatter(d0[0], d0[1], c='r')
plt.scatter(d1[0], d1[1], c='yellow')
plt.scatter(d2[0], d2[1], c='g')
plt.show()

# print the converged log-likelihood value
print(gmm.lower_bound_)

# print the number of interations needed
# for the log-likelihood value to converge
print(gmm.n_iter_)
```

Decision Tree

```
# Decision tree
import sklearn
import mglearn

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from IPython.display import Image, display
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
print(cancer.keys())

print(cancer['target_names'])
print(cancer['feature_names'])

# Build model using default setting that fully develops tree untill all leaves are
# Fix the random_state in the tree
# Evaluate using score() method

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, stratify = cancer.target, random_state = 42
)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Training set accuracy is 100% because leaves are pure
# Trees can become arbitrarily deep, complex, if depth of the tree is not limited
# Unpruned trees are prone to overfitting and not generalizing well to new data

print("Accuracy on the training PRE-PRUNING: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on the test set PRE-PRUNING': {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

# PRUNING
# Tree depth is limited to 4 branches
# Limiting depth of the tree decreases overfitting
# Results in lower accuracy on training set, but improvement on test set

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 4, random_state = 0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy on the training POST-PRUNING: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on the test set POST-PRUNING': {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

export_graphviz(tree, out_file="tree.dot", class_names=['malignant', 'benign'],
                feature_names=cancer.feature_names, impurity=False, filled=True)

from IPython.display import display
import graphviz

with open('tree.dot') as f:
  dot_graph = f.read()

display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))

# Even with tree with depth of only 4, tree becomes complex; deeper trees even harder to grasp
```

SVM

```
# Decision tree
import sklearn
import mglearn

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from IPython.display import Image, display
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
print(cancer.keys())

print(cancer['target_names'])
print(cancer['feature_names'])

# Build model using default setting that fully develops tree untill all leaves are
# Fix the random_state in the tree
# Evaluate using score() method

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, stratify = cancer.target, random_state = 42
)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Training set accuracy is 100% because leaves are pure
# Trees can become arbitrarily deep, complex, if depth of the tree is not limited
# Unpruned trees are prone to overfitting and not generalizing well to new data

print("Accuracy on the training PRE-PRUNING: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on the test set PRE-PRUNING': {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

# PRUNING
# Tree depth is limited to 4 branches
# Limiting depth of the tree decreases overfitting
# Results in lower accuracy on training set, but improvement on test set

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 4, random_state = 0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy on the training POST-PRUNING: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on the test set POST-PRUNING': {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

export_graphviz(tree, out_file="tree.dot", class_names=['malignant', 'benign'],
                feature_names=cancer.feature_names, impurity=False, filled=True)

from IPython.display import display
import graphviz

with open('tree.dot') as f:
  dot_graph = f.read()

display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))

# Even with tree with depth of only 4, tree becomes complex; deeper trees even harder to grasp
```

[image: Test]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [wxpython MouseEvent doc](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.MouseEvent.html) tells

> The position associated with a mouse event is expressed in the **window
>   coordinates** of the window which generated the event, you can use
>   `wx.Window.ClientToScreen` to convert it to screen coordinates and
>   possibly call `wx.Window.ScreenToClient` next to convert it to window
>   coordinates of another window.

pyautogui' `screenshot()` works with **screen coordinates**.

So, use `wx.Window.ClientToScreen` with both your `c1` and `c2`.

BTW, you should update `c2` also at `OnMouseUp` and check it not to be 'None' nor equal to `c1`.